# Vaadin ComboBox selects previous value instead of empty value

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin

I have a ComboBox, where as user types the values are loaded from a webservice. If no values are found, I want to reset the combobox to empty value. An example with fixed 2 items without using webservice:

```
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("First item");
comboBox.addItem("Second item");
comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);
comboBox.setInputPrompt("Select an item:");
comboBox.select("First item");
```

When I tried typing in input prompt "third" and then click away to loose focus, the "First item" stays selected.

When I tried to override this behaviour by manually calling `comboBox.select(null)` or `comboBox.select("")` or even `comboBox.setValue(null)`, still the "First item" stays selected.
 
This sound like a comboBox bug to me, but maybe somebody knows a workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As quick solution you can use this code. Simply add empty element into your combo box and on blur, or what ever action you needed, select it.

```
final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.addItem("");
comboBox.setNullSelectionItemId(comboBox.getItem(""));

comboBox.addItem("First item");
comboBox.addItem("Second item");
comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(true);
comboBox.setInputPrompt("Select an item:");
comboBox.select("First item");

comboBox.addListener(new BlurListener() {

@Override
public void blur(final BlurEvent event) {
        comboBox.setValue("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your code:

```
combobox.setImmediate(true);
```

This will display the selected value and not the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

As `removeAllItems()` doesn't work for `combobox`, you can remove individual items to get same effect.

E.g.:

```
//get state combos ids
```

List stateIDs = (List) state.getItemIds();

```
for(int i=0;i<stateIDs.size();i++){
    state.removeItem(stateIDs.get(i));
}
```